# Applying CSS to table created in JavaScript - Table not positioning in correct location

Tags: javascript, html, css

My issue is that a new grey box is being created, in the correct position, but the table generated from the JS code is positioned way below, and also appears over the footer when scrolling.

My CSS for this part is:

```
#contractTable {
position: relative;
width: 90%;  
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;  
background-color: #C0C0C0;
border: 1px solid black;
padding-top: 200px;
top: 200px;
}
```

a) How do I access the table in css? (as the code above appears to create a new box...)

b) How can I stop the table from scrolling on top of the footer?

c) There are several grey lines running across the screen. Does anyone know where these are coming from? and how I can get rid of these?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tHzWc/4/

Comment: It seems to me that all of these issues are caused because you do not understand the code which you are using. If you are using code which you found (on the internet for example), you should always try to understand it all and learn how it works. That way you will avoid issues like this in the future and learn new things while you're at it. Next time, you won't need to use code from the internet and you will be able to write it yourself (which is usually better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating 2 `contractTable`s in your Javascript. The following code creates a new table instead of using the existing one:

```
var contractTable = document.createElement("TABLE");
contractTable.setAttribute("id", "contractTable");
document.body.appendChild(contractTable);
```

If you replace that code with the following:

```
var contractTable = document.getElementById("contractTable");
```

Then it will use the existing table and put your items in there.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHzWc/7/)

> c) There are several grey lines running across the screen. Does anyone know where these are coming from? and how I can get rid of these?

These are `<hr>` tags, which you are inserting through Javascript:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
```

Since this code is in a `for` loop, they are actually added 3 times. Just removing this line of code gets rid of the grey lines.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHzWc/8/)

Comment: Thanks for such a helpful answer. This solved all of my problems, but now the text will not center align. I'm using #contractTable td to try this but text-align will not work here nor above in my original code. Do you know if this is the correct notation? I read around and it also says try #contractTable > td or > tr > td but none are working

Comment: @hturner `text-align: center;` does work, but your `td` elements are just not very big. You'll need to set a bigger width for it to be more visible. However, I just noticed that your `#contractTable` is a `<div>` instead of a `<table>`. Changing this and setting the table's width to 100% automatically increases the width of the cells and fixes the issue. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tHzWc/11/)

Comment: oops apologies. I wasn't looking at my html for the error so didn't notice this. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

solution to the question - b) :

```
#footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have HTML elements with the id = "contractTable", a div which is there initially and is getting styled by your CSS and this table that's getting created.  Remove the div.

Answer (score 0):

You have a div with id="contractTable" in your html. You then add a table to the end of the body of the html.

Try this:

```
<div id="contractTableContainer"></div>
```

...

```
contractTable.setAttribute("id", "contractTable");
ocument.getElementById('contractTableContainer').appendChild(contractTable);
```